# Use dplyr to convert all variables coded as "Y"/"N" to TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, YN_B = c('Y', 'N', 'N'), YN_C = c('N', 'N', 'Y'))
```

These variables that take values in c('Y', 'N') are not very useful to me. They would be much more useful encoded as TRUE for 'Y' and FALSE for 'N'. Helpfully, the Y/N columns are named in a way that lets me find them programmatically. I figure that `mutate_if` should be a help in that case.

I am trying to achieve this with mutate_if, which I haven't used before, but it's not quite working. Here's my attempt

```
df %>% mutate_if(matches('^YN'), .funs = funs(function(x) x == 'Y'))
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'p' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`matches` returns integer which specify the column position, however, `mutate_if` requires boolean values as predicate. In order to work with `matches` you can use `mutate_at` instead:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches('^YN')), funs(. == 'Y'))
#   A  YN_B  YN_C
# 1 1  TRUE FALSE
# 2 2 FALSE FALSE
# 3 3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Here is an example of how `matches` works:

```
matches('^YN', vars = c("A", "YN_B"))
# [1] 2
```

Add another case for `mutate_if` here, we can mutate columns based on the column types:

```
lapply(df, class)
# $A
# [1] "numeric"

# $YN_B
# [1] "character"

# $YN_C
# [1] "character"

df %>% mutate_if(is.character, funs(. == 'Y'))
#   A  YN_B  YN_C
# 1 1  TRUE FALSE
# 2 2 FALSE FALSE
# 3 3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need plyr for it. Melt your data frame with reshape2 package and recalculate your *value* column

```
df.long <- within(melt(df, 'A'), value <- value == 'Y')
```

Then cast it back

```
df.new <- dcast(df.long, A ~ variable)
```

Now you got it:

```
> df.new
  A  YN_B  YN_C
1 1  TRUE FALSE
2 2 FALSE FALSE
3 3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 >df %>% mutate(YN_B=(YN_B=="Y"),YN_C=(YN_C=="Y"))

          A  YN_B  YN_C
   (int) (lgl) (lgl)
1     1  TRUE FALSE
2     2 FALSE FALSE
3     3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- grep("YN", names(df))
setDT(df)[, paste0(i1, "L") := lapply(.SD, `==`, "Y"), .SDcols = i1]
```